# Deep dive into jQuery promises

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I 've just begun to study **promises**. I 've found them very interesting, however I have some queries I cannot find an answer.

1. I think that `$.Deferred().promise`, `$.get().promise` and `$.fn.promise().promise` are just the same function. *Am I right?*
2. If I am right for the previous question, why e.g.`$.Deferred().promise===$.get().promise` returns false?
3. `$('#mybox').hide(3000).promise()` for example, will create a promise object which **will be resolved once the animation queue will be empty**. What is the equivalent underlying procedure in case of:

   ```
     I.  $.get().promise() : Is it a queue that is being watched? If yes, which one? 
         If no, which is the trigger for the above promise object to be resolved?

     II. var defer=new $.Deferred().promise() : The same question!
   ```

Hope you help me to clarify the above...

Comment: You should avoid jquery promises because they don't follow the uniform promise proposal

Comment: 1. they are all a promise, but not the same promise, so 2. wont be == let  alone === 3.I. a promise gets resolved, any `then` (or similar) callbacks added will be called back in the same order they were attached, 3.II you wouldn't do that, because you have no access to the deferred fulfill/reject function to resolve the promise (unless jQuery exposes fulfill/reject in the returned promise)

Comment: @JaromandaX can you expand on your comment and post it as an answer if it answers the question(s)?

Answer (score 1):

1. Looking at the source, they are different functions, but they all return a promise
2. N/A
3. I. when a promise is resolved (through the resolve or reject), any `then`/`catch` (or similar in the case of jQuery) callbacks that were added will be called back in the same order they were attached
   II. you wouldn't want to do that, as you will not have access to the resolve/reject function in deferred to be able to resolve the promise - unless jQuery exposes resolve/reject in the returned promise, which doesn't seem to be the case

Answer (score 0):

1. Correct. They are all promise implementations.
2. Read [equality comparisons on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness). If all those methods are pointing to the same *function reference*, then yes they would be equal. However, since you're saying `===` is returning false, then this means that the methods were defined individually.
3. The trigger for the promise being resolved is when the animation completes. You'll need to look in the source code for that (meaning, it depends on their specific implementation of `hide`).

Comment: 1. - they are **not** the same function - read the jquery source